# Prevent VirtualService from routing to empty/unhealthy destinations?

Tags: kubernetes, istio

Is there a way to prevent a VirtualService from routing to empty/unhealthy destinations?
For example, consider the following VirtualService and DestinationRule:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: httpy
spec:
  hosts:
    - httpy
  http:
    - route:
      - destination:
          host: httpy
          subset: prod
        weight: 90
      - destination:
          host: httpy
          subset: canary
        weight: 10
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: httpy
spec:
  host: httpy
  subsets:
  - name: prod
    labels:
      isCanary: "false"
  - name: canary
    labels:
      isCanary: "true"
```

Imagine that there are no healthy pods in the `httpy` service that have the `isCanary: "true"` label either because A) zero pods have the `isCanary: "true"` label or B) all of the canary pods are unready/unhealthy.  This will result in 10% of requests to the `httpy` returning a "no healthy upstream" response.

Is there a good way to avoid this?  Is it possible to make the VirtualService "smarter" and have it not route traffic to an obviously unusable destination?

If you want to try this out yourself, apply the following gist then delete the `httpy-canary` deployment: https://gist.github.com/llamasoft/aaca58fda0ec2e06f2fee4f272691460

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in the destination rule You can configure `failover` with `LocalityLoadBalancerSetting`.

According to [istio](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/destination-rule/#LocalityLoadBalancerSetting) documentation:

> If the goal of the operator is not to distribute load across zones and regions but rather to restrict the regionality of failover to meet other operational requirements an operator can set a ‘failover’ policy instead of a ‘distribute’ policy.
>
> The following example sets up a locality failover policy for regions. Assume a service resides in zones within us-east, us-west & eu-west this example specifies that when endpoints within us-east become unhealthy traffic should failover to endpoints in any zone or sub-zone within eu-west and similarly us-west should failover to us-east.
>
> ```yaml
>  failover:
>    - from: us-east
>      to: eu-west
>    - from: us-west
>      to: us-east
> ```

Failover requires [outlier detection](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/destination-rule/#OutlierDetection) to be in place for it to work.

Hope it helps.